# How to make a token private

Tags: contract-development, transactions, anonymity, zksnark

How can I create a smart contract that has a function that receives an input ( either eth or another erc20 token ) and sends it to a specified address without revealing who sent it?

Basically making the transaction anonymous?

Is there any implementations of this as a smart contract?

Comment: Everything in the blockchain is public and can inspected by anyone having a copy of the blockchain. Since byzantinum fork there are available available some primitives to implement zkSnarks, but since ethereum addresses have to be used you do not have fully anonymous transactions.

Comment: @Ismael are there any examples of how to implement zk-snarks?

Comment: @AndroidDev93 It is better to ask a new question about that. But you can take a look at https://github.com/JacobEberhardt/ZoKrates

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `zeth` which is an implementation of the zerocoin protocol in an ethereum smart contract (https://github.com/zcoinofficial/zeth/blob/master/contracts/Zerocoin.sol) which you could integrate into a token contract. Do be warned though, zkSNARK computations on ethereum are expensive.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful for you https://www.ethereum.org/token.
Thanks

Comment: Hi there. Can you summarise the important parts from that article, and include them here? I know that's the "official" page, but it's possible it may be taken down or moved in future, meaning your answer won't be useful anymore. (Also, the OP is asking about _private_ tokens, rather than tokens in general.)

Answer (score 0):

As an idea you can implement a contract which receive a coin and "re-transfer" the coin to an address which is needed :-)